# How can I intercept a script's run() method in groovy from it's parent

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I'm trying to change how my groovy scripts are implemented just a little.  I still want them to run from the command line, but I'd really like to allow different methods to be called from within the same script (to group them) and I'd also like an automatic documentation system.

I'm trying to get a script like this to run:

```
@Doc("This is a test script")
public testScript(
    @Doc("Param 1 is optional") String param1="nobody"
)
{
    println "hello "+param1
}
```

if this was named, say "script" I could run that method by saying: "script testScript" or "script testScript world" from the command line.  If you used "script --help" you'd get a Usage display on your screen using the @Doc annotations.

The trick I'm hoping to use is Groovy's ability to specify a base class for a script.  If I use -b Base I can run Base's constructor before the child's "run" method is executed.

At this point I need to intercept the call that will soon come into "run" and I can't figure out how to do that.  No matter what I try, expandoMetaClass, invokeMethod, they won't intercept the call to the child's run() method. (I believe invokeMethod had some way to do "inheritence", but it needed a setup to run in main()..and scripts don't have one of those).

this would be trivial if I committed to using a batchfile or some other class to launch the script but I'd really rather not add anything more to the command line (I'm expecting to put the -b Base in an environment variable so scripts will still run just like you'd expect from the cli).

This is an example of my Base class...

```
abstract class Base extends Script implements GroovyInterceptable {
    public Base() {
        println "This is executed"
        assert(this.class.name == "script") // it is an instance of the child script
        def metaClass = this.class.getMetaClass() // should be script's meta
        metaClass.run = this.&myRun // I believe this is supposed to work
    }
    def myRun()
    {
        println "Never called, but the script is run after Base() returns"
    }
}
```